# Creating a program with c++ to calculate aspect ratio of given width and height values

Tags: c++

Create a program that will calculate the aspect ratio of your computer screen, given the                            width
           and height in pixels, using the following statements:
           int width = 1280;
            int height = 1024;
            double aspect = width / height;
When you output the result, what answer will you get? Is it satisfactory — and if not, how could
 you modify the code, without adding any more variables?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


int width = 1280;
int height = 1024;
double aspect = width / height;

cout << "aspect ration" << aspect << endl;


return 0;

}
```

I tried this code but It gave me value "1" .. I couldn't get the question .. what he meant by satisfactory ? and how can I modify the code without adding any variables ?

Comment: `int / int` will do integer division. To get floating point division, you need to convert at least one operand to floating point *before* the division happens. For aspect ratios, you may want a fraction in lowest terms (i.e., looking for GCD). In this case: 1280/256:1024/256=>5:4.

Comment: Why you tagged with `c++-cli`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing an integer division i.e if width is 3 and height is 2 it'd store 1 instead of 1.5 in `aspect`. One of the values should be double to make it a double division. Following should work:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int width = 1280;
    int height = 1024;
    double aspect = (double)width / height;

    cout << "aspect ration" << aspect << endl;


    return 0;

}
```